# SQL Server: incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I am trying to run the following T-SQL code which contains 8160 individual numbered accounts and receive the the following errors, with Line 10 being the first instance of INSERT and line 8162 being the last instance of INSERT

Code:

```
SELECT
    AXACNO AS [AGREEMENT],
    AX15C1 AS [BLOCKCODE]       
FROM
    BIDW_Staging.BPFCentrac.ACCEXTPF                
WHERE
    AXACNO IN (
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('0000000000000000')
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('1111111111111111')
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('2222222222222222')
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8162
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 1):

First you need to insert your data into your ##AN_INSERT table. Each INSERT is a separate statement and should be terminated with a `;`.

```
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('0000000000000000');
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('1111111111111111');
INSERT INTO ##AN_INSERT  VALUES ('2222222222222222');
```

Then you can select using this table:

```
select              
    AXACNO AS [AGREEMENT],
    AX15C1 AS [BLOCKCODE]       
from BIDW_Staging.BPFCentrac.ACCEXTPF              
Where AXACNO in 
   (SELECT <whatevercolumnthisis> FROM ##AN_INSERT);
```